# Matlab regression with multiple weights

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, weighted

I'm performing linear regression between a response variable, `y`, and a predictor, `x`, in Matlab using the function `fitlm`. In my analysis I also include a weight variable, `w`. However, the weight variable can only be one column vector, and I would like to control for multiple factors simultaneously. I have also tried the functions `robustfit`, `LinearModel.fit`, and `lscov`, but all these functions can only use a single column vector as weight.

Let me give you an example: `y` is response time to push a button, `x` is accuracy in response, and `weights = [gender age weight height]`. I want to be able to control for all these variables simultaneously. Is there a way to conduct such a multiple weights regression in Matlab?

Comment: Welcome to SO. These seems like an easy problem to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for. If people can run your code it's much easier to understand your question and you'll be more likely to get some help...

Comment: @lhcgeneva you can use `[mcve]` instead, it will directly print the link + written out acronym

Answer (score 1):

A weighted regression means that some data points are more or less important, i.e. if a point has a very high weight, it is not supposed to be far away from the model. What you describe is not a weighted regression.

In your case, you want to control for additional variables, which means that you fit a model of the form y = ax+b[gender]+c[age]+..., i.e. you are checking whether the other variables have a strong or weak explanatory effect.

For linearModel.fit you would therefore use

```
model = LinearModel.fit([x,gender,age,weight,height],y)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! I performed the analysis you suggest. However, because I already found that these variables, say [gender  age height] are also correlated with the response variable y, I want to be able to partial out their possible effects from the correlation between x and y, so that in the end I can say even when controlling for these factors  the relationship between x and y is still significant. I'm a newbie in this type of weighted regression so I'm really sorry if my comment is not clear.

Comment: Hi,
I think this Matlab function can do exactly what I want:
[rho,pval] = partialcorr(x,y,z)
which is to test the partial linear correlation between x and y while controlling for the variables in z. The drawback is that id doesn't have a subfunction to plot the the linear correlation between x and y.